# Aws Wordpress high I/O and redundancy

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services

I've deployed a wordpress stack in ec2 & efs which is not a great I/O's technology, it's been months trying to think of a better way (ebs) but that's almost impossible, unless you decide to make no changes to the website and mount the volume in each ec2 with userdata.

What are your thoughts, any smart ideas?

Comment: Amazon recommends using EFS in their Wordpress Best Practices paper https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/best-practices-wordpress/best-practices-wordpress.pdf As you are seeing, Wordpress is not really "cloud native" and is very difficult to scale across multiple servers. You should try serving images from S3 to see if that reduces the IO burden on your EFS volume. And also you should really look into a good CDN to reduce the amount of traffic your server has to handle, like Cloudflare https://www.cloudflare.com/automatic-platform-optimization/wordpress/

Comment: serving images from s3 is going to be a lot of extra config, I was thinking of uploading everything to s3 and configure userdata/autosaling to pull each time there's a new vm, or configure EBS's and mount them on boot.
 - I'll most likely use a CDN when the website is fully done, clearing the cache each time there's an update is annoying, I was thinking of Cloudfront but I'll take a serious look into Cloudflare. thank you!

Comment: Cloudflare has much better support for WordPress, in my experience it is much better than CloudFront for a WordPress site. As for serving images from S3, you would use a plugin for that, like https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/

Comment: This is epic mate thank you! I was determined to go for Cloudfront just because I'm developing my APIs/lambdas in Go but this is a deal-breaker, thank you kindly for the awesome tip! I'm more than happy/open to more similar suggestions.

Comment: Definitely read up on the WordPress APO feature in Cloudflare. Between that, and the tiered caching feature, I have a fairly high-traffic WordPress site that has over 92% of it's requests served by Cloudflare without hitting the actual WordPress server at all. I'm using AWS EFS with this site, and it hardly sees any use except when editors are logged into WordPress updating the site.

Comment: Hey Mark - something that it's been bugging me and keep thinking about is how did you monitor the traffic that goes to the CDN vs the instance? I'm really curious how to figure that thing out, vpc flowlogs or ELB logs won't do the trick I believe. Much appreciate your great help!

Comment: Cloudflare has analytics dashboards that show you how much traffic they are serving via cache versus sending to the origin server. That information would only be available at the CDN, since any traffic served by the CDN would never be in your VPC at all. If you were using CloudFront I believe there would be some metrics in CloudWatch for this.

Answer (score 0):

The original question omits performance requirements, therefore it's hard to give a definitive answer but EFS shouldn't be a bottleneck.

Recently AWS announced [increased maximum throughput per EFS file system](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/04/amazon-efs-10-gibs-throughput/) - 250,000 read and 50,000 write IOPS with throughput reaching 10 GiB/s and 3 GiB/s respectively. To achieve these numbers you'll need to distribute the workload across 10 or more NFS clients, with at least 64 threads per client in a single mount target [(see docs here)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/performance.html#recs-intensive-workloads).

It means that you'll need to scale WordPress instances horizontally to increase EFS throughput.

Additionally, EFS performance seems to be correlated with the total size of EFS volume. Therefore, either use provisioned throughput or add a large file into the volume.

Also, make sure that OPCache is enabled and maybe even leverage Memcached/ElastiCache. A typical HTTP request would need to access many, in some cases 100+ small PHP files. We want to avoid that.

Finally, you can leverage CloudFront CDN for offloading traffic from EC2/ECS instances. This can be applied to frequently accessed, rarely updated WordPress posts as well as static content like images, CSS, and JavaScript.

AWS's reference architecture [whitepaper](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pdfs/whitepapers/latest/best-practices-wordpress/best-practices-wordpress.pdf) covers some of these points and there are [implementations](https://www.infrasource.io/blueprints/wordpress-aws#performance-and-scalability) that claim similar performance objectives.